# Jquery inside Html.Raw()

Tags: jquery, razor

Is it possible to write jQuery code inside razor `Html.Raw()` method. I have a model, who has a property named body. body is a html string. I use `Html.Raw(model.body)` to render html in the page. Is it possible to include jquery code in the string, to control the ids and classes in the html string of body.

I tried using inline `<script></script>` tag but it didn't work.

Comment: using inline <script></script> ?

Comment: The output from Razor (/MVC) is always just text.  Server-side code helps to manipulate that text with data etc, but once it goes over the wire to the browser, it's *always* just text. Whether that text comes from `.Raw(data)` or directly in the razor .cshtml is irrelevant.

Comment: What have you actually tried in your `model.body` ?

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.pop').hover(function(){
                alert("Ollo");
            });
        });
</script>

I have added this script where pop is a class of a link which is also in the body. Is it possible to write jquery in the cshtml file I have write Html.Raw(), and control the ids and classes of the Html.Raw() generated elements.